# Почему не работает функция внутри конструктора? Python

Tags: python-3.5

Создайте класс, описывающий температуру и позволяющий задавать и получать температуру по шкале Цельсия и Фаренгейта, причём данные могут быть заданы в одной шкале, а получены в другой

```
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self, value, system):
        if system == 'f':
            self.__k = __f_to_k(int(value))
        elif system == 'c':
            self.__k = __c_to_k(int(value))


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Temperature <{}>".format(self.__k)


    def __k_to_f(v):
        """Перевод из кельвина в фаренгейт"""
        return 1.8 * (v - 273) + 32


    def __f_to_k(v):
        """Перевод из фаренгейт в кельвина"""
        return ((v - 32) / 1.8) + 273


    def __k_to_c(v):
        """Перевод из кельвина в цельсий"""
        return v - 273


    def __c_to_k(v):
        """Перевод из цельсия в кельвина"""
        return v + 273


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Temperature(0, 'f')
    print(repr(t))
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение проблемы в самом внизу.**

Потому что внутри класса не пишите `self.<название поля или метода>`.

Т.е. должно быть не `__f_to_k(int(value))`, а `self.__f_to_k(int(value))`

Это связанно с идеалогией автора питона о том, что открытое лучше скрытого.

Например, в некоторых языках (с++, java, c#, и т.п.) можно было написать и `__f_to_k(int(value))` и `this.__f_to_k(int(value))`, и для первого случая функция __f_to_k могла оказаться вне класса (как глобальная) и оказаться методом класса. Для второго же случая с указанием `this.`, всегда было понятно что она относится к классу.

---

`self` используется везде в методах классов, которые могут быть вызваны объектом класса, чтобы функция могла быть вызвана самим классом (или его объектом) она должна стать статичной.

```
# t теперь хранит сcылку на объект
t = Temperature(20, 'f')

# Добавим в класс метод def get_value(self)
# Объект t вызывает метод и свою ссылку передает в параметр self
t.get_value()
```

Теперь о статичных методов. Она не имеют первого параметра и у них присутствует декоратор `@staticmethod`, например:

```
@staticmethod
def k_to_f(v):
    """Перевод из кельвина в фаренгейт"""
    return 1.8 * (v - 273) + 32
```

Благодаря нему при `t.k_to_f(20)` не нужно будет создавать объект и в метод не будет передаваться ссылка на объект как для примера с `self`. Также можно вызывать метод и без создания объекта `Temperature.k_to_f(20)`

---

Чтобы ваш код заработал:

1. Методы класса без первого параметра `self` сделайте или статичными, или добавьте `self`: `k_to_f(v)` -> `k_to_f(self, v)`
2. Вызывайте методы класса с `self.` для тех что нестатичные и через класс или `self.` для статичных

Еще можно поиздеваться и добавить функцию вне класса, тогда ошибка пропадет:

```
def _Temperature__f_to_k(v):
    pass
```

Но это: не круто и неправильно. Почитайте про волшебные методы питона и как в нем разграничение доступа к полям и методам сделано и станет понятно как `__f_to_k` стала `_Temperature__f_to_k`

Answer (score 0):

Не называй методы класса с `__` , т.к в Питоне нет приватных полей, такие имена используют для псевдо-приватных методов, в стиле `__str__`.

Comment: да, инкапсулировать конечно нельзя с помощью __ но IDE такие поля и методы не выдает. Например у меня vs 2017 comm, и если галочка поставлена в нужном месте, в настройках, то vs  не выдает эти поля в intellisense

Answer (score 0):

можно еще отнаследоватся от стандартных классов(например dict), получается компактно

```
class Temperature(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.update(kwargs)

        if 'f' in self:
            self['k'] = ((self['f'] - 32) / 1.8) + 273
        elif 'c' in self:
            self['k'] = self['c'] + 273

        self['c'] = self['k'] - 273
        self['f'] = 1.8 * self['c'] + 32

print(Temperature(c=100))  # {'c': 100, 'k': 373, 'f': 212.0}
```